# WebGL Texture doesn't works

Tags: three.js, textures, webgl

I want to apply texture on a cube with the three.sj 3D librairie but it dosn't works and i didn't find my mistake.
I succeed to apply on a plan in the background but not on a cube , i don't know why

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/images/texture/ciel.jpg')
});

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200), material);
cube.overdraw = true;
cube.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.1; 
scene.add(cube);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your scene animated?

Sometimes, loading textures can be problem if the scene is not animated, because, you currently don't have any code to re-render the scene after it's finished loading texture, or at least wait for the texture to load before rendering the scene.

In both ways, it's probably the best to re-draw the scene after the load has finished so you need to attach the callback function that will do just that, after the loading.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map:
    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/images/texture/ciel.jpg', undefined, function() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    });
});
```

See [ImageUtils docs](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras/ImageUtils) to understand what are the parameters of the `loadTexture` function.